# Facebook on share doesn't show image

Tags: facebook

When I share link of my site on facebook it doesn't show image.

I put meta tags like this:

```
<meta property="og:title" content="Ledeni čaj Limona Breskev"/>
    <meta property="og:description" content="Ledeni čajček z okusom breskve in limone je mešanica zelenega čaja, zelišč in koščkov sadja in ponuja vse pozitivne učinkovine zelenega čaja"/>
    <meta property="og:url" content="http://www.zisha.si/izdelki_zeleni_caji/caj_ledeni_caj_limona_breskev/"/>
    <meta property="og:image" content="http://www.zisha.si/typo3temp/pics/f925485212.jpg"/>
    <link rel="image_src" type="image/jpeg" href="http://www.zisha.si/typo3temp/pics/f925485212.jpg" />
```

But when I share this link:

http://www.zisha.si/izdelki_zeleni_caji/caj_ledeni_caj_limona_breskev/

It doesnt show my image? I even checked with https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/, and everything is shown. But when I share it on my wall the image is missing?

Comment: For this url: http://www.zisha.si/izdelki_crni_caji/caj_zimska_poezija/ it doesn't even take description??

Comment: Your `og:image` is too small, it must be at least `200x200 px`